# How i can use Graphite with check_snmp (icinga2)?

Tags: python, snmp, icinga2, icingaweb2

I'm using graphite to display my services, but only display the default services (http, disk, ssh, etc ...).
[image]

I add check_snmp command but Graphite does not recognize it

[image]

Hope Somebody can Help me, thanks :)

Comment: You able to fix this issue ? I too have the same doubt.

Comment: Hi, I recommend you to check permissions over where you save the Graphite data, (in my case /opt/graphite/storage/whisper/icinga2). I think the problem was solved with that.

Comment: Really appreciate your reply. I modified the icinga2 transoprt mode from local to API in file - /etc/icingaweb2/modules/monitoring/commandtransports.ini. which resolved the issue.